# Python3 - TypeException take 1 argument 2 where given

Tags: python, arguments

The program i am working on have a class with constructor defined as follow :

```
def Oracle(object) :
Agold = None
sentence = None

def __init__(self, sentence, Agold):
    self.Agold = Agold
    self.sentence = sentence
```

but, when i call the constructor in my main method, as follow :

```
oracle = Oracle(words, ref_tree)
```

python 3 give me this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "oracle_test.py", line 52, in test_exemple
oracle = Oracle(words, ref_tree)
TypeError: Oracle() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

i don't understand the origin of this problem, and i don't see what gone wrong.

Can someone give me an explanation ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined `Oracle` as a function instead of a class. Use `class` instead of `def`. Also, assuming `Agold` and `sentence` are supposed to be instance variables instead of class variables, `Agold = None` and `sentence = None` are not needed (see [this](https://syntaxdb.com/ref/python/class-variables)).

```
class Oracle(object):
    def __init__(self, sentence, Agold):
        self.Agold = Agold
        self.sentence = sentence
```